# dropwizard metrics to google stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, dropwizard, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am running a dropwizard application in Google Compute Engine (Instance group setup).

Google cloud provides extensive monitoring with stackdriver agent installed in Compute Engine. Dropwizard provides apis to collect default metrics.

How to ship dropwizard metrics to stackdriver?

- JMX metrics
- Number of HTTP requests per second

Comment: You can use this [link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/) to create and use custom metrics. It also describes how to use the Stackdriver Monitoring API to create custom metrics and to add time series data to them.
You can find [some examples](https://medium.com/@ludomagno/stackdriver-custom-metrics-the-easy-way-on-gcp-bd0530a04e19) of the Stackdriver custom metrics.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the JVM [plugin](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/jvm) to monitor these metrics.

Comment: I followed exactly the same one. What I am not clear is, it asks for jmx port. Then should I start the java process like 


/usr/bin/java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false  -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -jar my.jar server config.yaml
? and give the port name as 9010?

Comment: This comment seems to be asking a question about enabling JMX in your JVM, which should be posted as a separate question (if I understand StackOverflow etiquette correctly) under the proper tag.